# powershell extract text between two strings

Tags: regex, powershell

I know this question has been asked before but I can't get any of the answers I have looked at to work. I have a JSON file which has thousands of lines and want to simply extract the text between two strings every time they appear (which is a lot).

As a simple example my JSON would look like this:

```
    "customfield_11300": null,
    "customfield_11301": [
      {
        "self": "xxxxxxxx",
        "value": "xxxxxxxxx",
        "id": "10467"
      }
    ],
    "customfield_10730": null,
    "customfield_11302": null,
    "customfield_10720": 0.0,
    "customfield_11300": null,
    "customfield_11301": [
      {
        "self": "zzzzzzzzzzzzz",
        "value": "zzzzzzzzzzz",
        "id": "10467"
      }
    ],
    "customfield_10730": null,
    "customfield_11302": null,
    "customfield_10720": 0.0,
```

So I want to output everything between "customfield_11301" and "customfield_10730":

```
      {
        "self": "xxxxxxxx",
        "value": "xxxxxxxxx",
        "id": "10467"
      }
    ],
      {
        "self": "zzzzzzzzzzzzz",
        "value": "zzzzzzzzzzz",
        "id": "10467"
      }
    ],
```

I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible - so don't care about brackets being displayed in the output.

This is what I have (which outputs way more than what I want):

```
$importPath = "todays_changes.txt"
$pattern = "customfield_11301(.*)customfield_10730"

$string = Get-Content $importPath
$result = [regex]::match($string, $pattern).Groups[1].Value
$result
```

Comment: why don't you decode the JSON into an object and address the properties directly?

Comment: The quick answer is - change your greedy capture `(.*)` to non greedy - `(.*?)`. That should do it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The quick answer is - change your greedy capture `(.*)` to non greedy - `(.*?)`. That should do it.

```
customfield_11301(.*?)customfield_10730
```

Otherwise the capture will eat as much as it can, resulting in it continuing 'til the last `customfield_10730`.

Regards

Comment: With this approach if I have multiple times the same pattern on a single line , it only returns the first occurence . Any idea on how to apply this to multiple occurrences in the same line ?

Answer (score 13):

Here is a PowerShell function which will find a string between two strings.

```
function GetStringBetweenTwoStrings($firstString, $secondString, $importPath){

    #Get content from file
    $file = Get-Content $importPath

    #Regex pattern to compare two strings
    $pattern = "$firstString(.*?)$secondString"

    #Perform the opperation
    $result = [regex]::Match($file,$pattern).Groups[1].Value

    #Return result
    return $result

}
```

You can then run the function like this:

```
GetStringBetweenTwoStrings -firstString "Lorem" -secondString "is" -importPath "C:\Temp\test.txt"
```

My test.txt file has the following text within it:

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

So my result:

> Ipsum

Comment: There are several limitations to note:
Only _one_ match is returned, whereas the question asks for _all_.
Due to using `Get-Content` without `-Raw`, your function inadvertently _modifies_ the file's content before matching, by turning it into a space-separated _single-line_ string first.
`$firstString` and `$secondString`, despite what the parameter names suggest, must be _regex patterns_, not literal strings.
For simple strings that contain no regex metacharacters, such as in this case, that won't be a problem, but if you pass literal strings such as `'foo(`, your function breaks.

Comment: As an aside: it's better to observe PowerShell's Verb-Noun naming convention -> `GetStringBetweenTwoStrings` -> `Get-StringBetweenTwoStrings`

Answer (score 5):

You need to make your RegEx *Lazy*:

```
customfield_11301(.*?)customfield_10730
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/eD1gG1/1)</kbd>

Your Regex was *Greedy*. This means it will find `customfield_11301`, and then carry until it finds the **very last** `customfield_10730`.

Here is a simpler example of Greedy vs Lazy Regex:

```
# Regex (Greedy): [(.*)]
# Input:          [foo]and[bar]
# Output:         foo]and[bar

# Regex (Lazy):   [(.*?)]
# Input:          [foo]and[bar]
# Output:         "foo" and "bar" separately
```

Your Regex was very similar to the first one, it captured too much, whereas this new one captures the least amount of data possible, and will therefore work as you intended

Comment: Thank you kindly for your help, @ClasG answered a few minutes before you so I'll accept his as the answer. But thank you especially for the regex101 demo link, that really helped me understand what was happening.

Answer (score 2):

First issue is `Get-Content` pipe will give you line by line not the entire content at once. You can pipe `Get-Content` with `Out-String` to get entire content as a single string and do the Regex on the content.

A working solution for your problem is:

`Get-Content .\todays_changes.txt | Out-String | % {[Regex]::Matches($_, "(?<=customfield_11301)((.|\n)*?)(?=customfield_10730)")} | % {$_.Value}`

And the output will be:

```
": [
  {
    "self": "xxxxxxxx",
    "value": "xxxxxxxxx",
    "id": "10467"
  }
],
"

": [
  {
    "self": "zzzzzzzzzzzzz",
    "value": "zzzzzzzzzzz",
    "id": "10467"
  }
],
"
```

Comment: Use `Get-Content -Raw` to get a file's entire content as a single, multiline string.

Answer (score 0):

As an aside: Since your input appears to be JSON, you're normally better off parsing it into an object graph with [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json), which you can easily query; however, your JSON appears to be *nonstandard* in that it contains *duplicate property names*.

---

There's good information in the existing answers, but let me try to cover all aspects in a single answer:

**tl;dr**

```bash
# * .Matches() (plural) is used to get *all* matches
# * Get-Content -Raw reads the file *as a wole*, into a single, multiline string
# * Inline regex option (?s) makes "." match newlines too, to match *across lines*
# * (.*?) rather than (.*) makes the matching *non-greedy*.
# * Look-around assertions - (?<=...) and (?=...) - to avoid the need for capture groups.
[regex]::Matches(
  (Get-Content -Raw todays_changes.txt),
  '(?s)(?<="customfield_11301":).*?(?="customfield_10730")'
).Value
```

Output with your sample input:

```json
 [
      {
        "self": "xxxxxxxx",
        "value": "xxxxxxxxx",
        "id": "10467"
      }
    ],
    
 [
      {
        "self": "zzzzzzzzzzzzz",
        "value": "zzzzzzzzzzz",
        "id": "10467"
      }
    ],
```

For an explanation of the regex and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/9QD6At/1)

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `$pattern = "customfield_11301(.*)customfield_10730"`

As has been noted, the primary problem with this regex is that `(.*)` is *greedy*, and will keep matching until the *last* occurrence of `customfield_10730` has been found; making it *non-greedy* - `(.*?)` solves that problem.

Additionally, this regex will *not* match *across multiple lines*, because `.` by default does not match *newline* characters (`\n`). The easiest way to change that is to place inline regex option `(?s)` at the start of the pattern, as shown above.

It was only a *lucky accident* that still caused cross-line matching in your attempt, as explained next:

> `$string = Get-Content $importPath`

This stores an *array* of strings in `$string`, with each element representing a *line* from the input file.

To read a file's content *as a whole* into a *single, multiline string*, use [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content)'s `-Raw` switch: `$string = Get-Content -Raw $importPath`

> `$result = [regex]::match($string, $pattern).Groups[1].Value`

Since your `$string` variable contained an *array* of strings, PowerShell *implicitly stringified it* when passing it to the `[string]` typed `input` parameter of the [`[regex]::Match()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match) method, which effectively created a *single-line* representation, because the array elements are joined *with spaces* (by default; you can specify a different separator with `$OFS`, but that is rarely done in practice).

For instance, the following two calls are - surprisingly - equivalent:

```bash
[regex]::Match('one two'), 'e t').Value # -> 'e t'

# !! Ditto, because array @('one', 'two') stringifies to 'one two'
[regex]::Match(@('one', 'two'), 'e t').Value # -> 'e t'
```